# How to add an adsense amphtml ad to a webpage?

Tags: html, css, ads, amp-html, adsense

I can't find any information on how to add amphtml to a non-amp web page, specifically using an adsense ad. There's code for how to build the ad creative itself, but not how to display the ad on a web page.

Does anyone how to do this?

Comment: It clearly says you can do this on the official AMP page: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/intro-to-amphtml-ads/  "6. More Flexible: AMPHTML ads are designed to work on both AMP and non-AMP web pages, as well as across any device."

Answer (score 1):

As AdSense publisher currently there is no way to force only AMP ads serving. AdSense publishers get regular HTML5 ads. Can you elaborate on why you want to get AMP ads on your non-AMP website?

Comment: One reason would be that AMP ads seem to be lighter weight in terms of page loading times (specifically, metrics like "Total Blocking Time" in Lighthouse/PageSpeed Insights) compared to conventional HTML5 ads.